# React create object of simple object with map iterator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm studying React and json objects, but I can't obtain what i want:

Here is the code:

```
const selectOptions1 = {
    9: 'good',
    14: 'Bad',
    26: 'unknown'
  };

  const selectOptions2 = options.map((item) => {
    return (
      { [item.value]:item.label }
    )
  })

  console.log(selectOptions1) // {9:good, 14:bad, 26:unknown}
  console.log(selectOptions2) // [{…}, {…}, {…}] -> 0: {9: "good"} 1: {14: "bad"} 2: {26: "unknown"}
```

How can I create an object like selectOptions1 using map (instead of the structure like in selectOptions2)?

Comment: what is `options` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of map

```js
const options = [
  {value: 1, label : 'one'},
  {value: 2, label : 'two'},
  {value: 3, label : 'three'},
  {value: 41, label : 'four'},
  {value: 32, label : 'five'},
]

var obj = options.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  return {
    [current.value]: current.label,
    ...accumulator,
  }
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Because map transform every item into a new one and returns a list of the same length with the transformation applied. you are transforming every {value, label} object into a new {value, label} object.

reduce accumulates and returns only one result, that can be a list or something else if you have creativity with it, here i'm using the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to accumulate keys in one object.